# AJAX get method trouble with getting values from db with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im trying to get some values from my db to my ajax method using GET. the code seems fine to me, but im not sure whats going wrong here

ajax method to get values from db-

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){//comparing the total quoted hours with duration of time selected 

    ticket_id = $('#ticket_id').val();
    total_hours = $('#total_hours').val();
    // alert(ticket_id); // this shows up and comes up as undefined

    $.ajax({
        url: 'comp_time.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {ticket_id: ticket_id, total_hours: total_hours} ,
        success: function (response) {

            alert(total_hours) // get the total hours from comp_time.php 

        }
    }); 
});
```

comp_time.php-

```
<?php
    include("../includes/connect.php");
    $ticket_id = $_REQUEST['ticket_id'];
    $total_hours = $_REQUEST['total_hours'];

    $sql="SELECT total_hours FROM `cmp_ticket_repository` WHERE ticket_id = '$ticket_id'";
    $query_sql=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql) or die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]));

    if( mysqli_num_rows($query_sql) > 0){
        $row_sql=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_sql);

        echo $row_sql['total_hours'];
    }
    else{
        echo 'invalid';
    }
?>
```

i want to be able to get those values from the db and store them in a var to be able to compare its values with other values. ive written this code following another function with ajax get that a friend of mine wrote and is pretty much written in the same manner.

Comment: Open DevTools the in the network tab see what errors you are getting.

Comment: _“but im not sure whats going wrong here”_ - neither are we, because you did not even give us an actual problem description. Please go read [ask].

Comment: `alert(total_hours) // get the total hours from comp_time.php` – `total_hours` here has nothing to do with the PHP script, it’s just the variable you assigned a value to here before, `total_hours = $('#total_hours').val();`. Your PHP script just outputs a value - that doesn’t create or change any variables in JS. What your PHP script returned, is contained in `response` here.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi theres no errors

Comment: You are also not handling errors in your AJAX request. Add this line after success function : `error: (err) => console.log(err)` & see what you get there on the console.

Comment: @misorude im not able to retrieve the values from the db under total_hours, thats what i want to show in alert

Comment: @RopAliMunshi okay ill try that, thanks

Comment: _“im not able to retrieve the values from the db under total_hours”_ - there is no reason why your PHP code should change that client-side variable, there is just no connection between the two whatsoever. Again: The full response of your server-side script can be found inside the `response` parameter.

Comment: @misorude i see. ill try going through some documentation and try it again. thanks for the help!

Comment: Let's strat from simple: are your ajax script and comp_tipe.php in same directory?

Comment: @Dmitry yes same directory

Comment: @RohanKorde skip database connection and try to echo `$_GET['ticket_id']`.
        `success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }` alert window should show you this value;

Comment: yeah thanks i got it working now

Answer (score 0):

> ajax method to get values from db-

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){//comparing the total quoted hours with duration of time selected 

    ticket_id = $('#ticket_id').val();
    total_hours = $('#total_hours').val();
    // alert(ticket_id); // this shows up and comes up as undefined

    $.ajax({
        url: 'comp_time.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {ticket_id: ticket_id, total_hours: total_hours} ,
        success: function (response) {

            alert(response) // get the total hours from comp_time.php 

        }
    }); 
});
```

> comp_time.php-

```
<?php
    include("../includes/connect.php");
    $ticket_id = $_REQUEST['ticket_id'];
    $total_hours = $_REQUEST['total_hours'];

    $sql="SELECT total_hours FROM `cmp_ticket_repository` WHERE ticket_id = '$ticket_id'";
    $query_sql=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql) or die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]));

    if( mysqli_num_rows($query_sql) > 0){
        $row_sql=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_sql);

        echo $row_sql['total_hours']; exit;
    }
    else{
        echo 'invalid'; exit;
    }
?>
```